# How to correctly write declarations of extern arrays (and double arrays) in C's header files?

Tags: c, arrays, header, declaration, extern

Suppose I want to share a global array of data across my program, for example:

```
int lookup_indexes[] = { -1, 1, 1, -1, 2, 1, 1, -2, 2, 2, -1, 1, 1, 2 };
```

What is the correct `extern` declaration for this array in the C header file?

Also what about an array like this:

```
int double_indexes[][5] = { { -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 }, { 2, -2, 2, 1, -1 } };
```

In my header file I tried this:

```
extern int lookup_indexes[];
extern int double_indexes[][5];
```

But this results in compiler errors:

```
water.h:5: error: array type has incomplete element type
```

I can't figure it out.

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `water.h` at least up to line 5 and show which line is causing the error.

Comment: Charles, it's #ifndef, #define, a newline and `extern int lookup_indexes[];` (4th line) and `extern int double_indexes[][5];` (5th line).

Comment: he meant to put it in your question. Just append it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071890/external-delaration-for-an-array

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://c-faq.com/decl/extarraysize.html) link discusses the problems with  arrays and sizes used as extern and how to manage them.

1. Declare a companion variable, containing the size of the array, defined and initialized (with sizeof) in the same source file where the array is defined
2. ## define a manifest constant for the size so that it can be used consistently in the definition and the extern declaration
3. Use some sentinel value (typically 0, -1, or NULL) in the array's last element, so that code can determine the end without an explicit size indication

Comment: +1 for mentioning array size. The compiler simply has no information about the size of the array if it isn't explicitly declared in the header file

Comment: I don't believe this is the OP's problem or question: He doesn't want to know the size of his arrays, he just wants to properly declare them. Links the the C-FAQ are always good of course.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted looks fine to me and compiles (`gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` and `gcc -std=c90 -pedantic`) on my machine. Have you copy-pasted these lines or could you have made a typo in your real header?

Example typos that could cause your error (pure guesswork):

```
extern int double_indexes[][];  /* forgot the 5 */
extern int double_indexes[5][]; /* [] and [5] swapped */
```