# Accessing an array across files in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to access an array across files, like this;

```
int option[NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS];
...
addition(&option[0], num1, num2); 
...
printf("%d", option[0]);
```

thats the first(main) file

and the second is like this;

```
void addition(int * option, unsigned number1, unsigned number2)
{
int total = number1 + number2;
...
*option ++;
}
```

Something like that. Dont worry about the addition method.

The problem is that the printf method allways prints 0, as if *option ++; is never executed/read.

How do i fix this?

By the way, I get a warning in the "*option++;" file saying: warning: value computed is not used.

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: This code should not even compile. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
*option++;
```

doesn't do what you think it does. What it actually means is:

```
*(option++);
```

which first applies the increment operator to the `option` pointer and dereferences it afterwards. The effect is:

```
option++;
*option; // This is a statement with no effect, hence the warning.
```

You need this instead:

```
(*option)++;
```

Comment: It _is_ valid. It is the same as `*(option ++);`. And the compiler already gave a warning, suspecting that something was not right.

Comment: You are incorrect in the latter part of the answer: the option is an lvalue. Even if called with int value[] syntax, it is an lvalue.

Comment: @DanielDaranas because the effect of expression `*option ++;` is just `option++;`, an lhs variable missing. its should be like:  `x = *option ++;`

Comment: @DanielDaranas, AnttiHaapala: The correct term is "modifiable lvalue". I corrected the answer. Other than that, the code is not valid. A warning is not enough; the code should actually not compile at all.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Lets say I want to access the option[] from the second file, how do I access it?

Comment: @user2621292 You need to have an `extern` declaration in the second file. See the first two answers to this question on how that looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071890/external-delaration-for-an-array

Comment: You're wrong about `*option++` being something that shouldn't compile. If you look closely, you'll see that at the point where `option` is being incremented, is inside the `addition()` function. In that scope, `option` is a pointer that was passed to the function.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson You're right. A good real-life example of why shadowing a variable from an enclosing scope is a bad idea; people get confused :-)

Answer (score 2):

`++` has a higher priority than `*`. So `*option ++;` is the same as `*(option ++);`, which do nothing (that's why you get the warning).

Try this:

`(*option) ++;`

Answer (score 1):

`*` binds looser than `++`, so `*option ++ = *(option++)`; to modify the values in array, you need to write `(*option)++`; that is, the suffix increment has higher precedence than the dereference operator