# extern arrays in c without size

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof, extern

Not compiling:

```
int a[];
```

Compiling:

```
extern int a[];
```

Not compiling (it can't find sizeof):

```
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
```

So questions:

1. why it is possible to create extern array.
2. how much memory allocated?

The reason of question - http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~rbaeza/handbook/algs/4/444.sort.c

```
extern int maxfiles, maxruns[], actruns[];
for (i=0; i<=maxfiles; i++) maxruns[i] = actruns[i] = 0;
```

Is it correct?

Comment: external variables need to be linked....

Comment: possible duplicate of [External Delaration for An Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071890/external-delaration-for-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.)  You have not **created** an `extern` array.  Rather, you have declared that an array exists, and it was created somewhere else (*externally*).  And where it was created, it does have a specific size.

2.) Because you have not created an array, **no** size is allocated for it.  (see #1).  Rather, the array was created in another file/module/component (externally), and this is a declaration that the array exists, and may be accessed here.